# React Beautiful D&D Cannot get dimension when no ref is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui, react-beautiful-dnd

Hello there community!

So I'm in the middle of developing a meta form creator and I'm running into some performance issues. I made a sandbox to ask the question but I'm running into this "Cannot get dimension when no ref is set" error when i try to drag a second card over in the sandbox.

I've played with every ref I've set to try to work it out but can't seem to.

Here is the code sandbox. Fun to play with full screen . You drag the card over and click to expand, then you can edit the input.

[Code Sanbox For Material UI Form Creator](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-jackson-z3ppp)

Comment: Please put your code here as well, in your question, in text format as a [mre], not just on an external site.  External sites go down, and if that happens, your question becomes useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SimpleFormCreator.jsx line number 721, you have a div which needs to have its `ref` property set to provided.innerRef.

Change it like this:

```
 <div
    style={{width: "max-content",flex: "50%",marginBottom: 10}}
    ref={provided.innerRef}>
    {...}
 </div>
```

[Refer to this issue on rbd github](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2047).
If this does not solve your issue, you probably have other places where you haven't passed the ref to the inner container element. If possible try to post a minimal version of your code that reproduces the error so we don't have to debug your entire application. Right now, there are a lot of places where you could have used `<Draggable>` or `<Droppable>` components, both of which require the top element to have the ref set. Debugging that could take a while.